# Thrift TServer serve does not return to main thread

Tags: java, thrift

Following is how i have implemented the `thrift` server, but it does not return to main therad after the `serve()` call.

```
public class ThriftServerRunner implements Runnable {
    private int thriftServerPort;
    public ThriftServerRunner(int thriftServerPort, LogWriter logWriter) {
        this.thriftServerPort = thriftServerPort;   
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            SetupThriftServer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }

    private void SetupThriftServer() throws Exception {
    try {
            TServerSocket serverTransport = new TServerSocket(this.thriftServerPort);
            ThriftService.Processor<ThriftService.Iface> processor = new ThriftService.Processor(new ThriftServiceImpl());
            TServer server = new TThreadPoolServer(new TThreadPoolServer.Args(serverTransport).processor(processor));
        server.serve();      
    } catch (TTransportException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do call `start()` to start the thread (which will create a new thread, then call the objects `run()`function from this new thread) , and not `run()` (which will just run `run()` from the same thread as you're currently in), right?

`serve()` is not meant to return, unless you stop the server (from another thread).